# Matching numbers with non-digits embedded

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I am trying to match strings of digits that contain non-digits within them. Using the default text in http://regexr.com/, the following should match:

```
v2.1
-98.7
3.141
.6180
9,000 
+42
555.123.4567    
+1-(800)-555-2468
```

The following should *not* match:

```
0123456789
12345
```

I tried:

```
/[^\n\ ]{1,}\d+\S+\d/g
```

But it would not match `+42` and it incorrectly matched `0123456789` and `12345`, and it treated `"555.123.4567 +1-(800)-555-2468"` as one string.

I tried to alleviate it by putting a `$` at the end but that matched nothing. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex to match any text with at least one non-digit:

```
/^\d*[^\d\n]+\d.*$/mg
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xR1dK7/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^` - Start
- `\d*` - Match 0 or more digits
- `[^\d\n]+` - Match 1 or more of any character that is not a digit and not a newline
- `\d` - Match a digit
- `.*` - Match 0 or more of any character
- `$` - End

Comment: I should have commented that it matches a non-digit string as well. Like a sentence.

Comment: Title is *Matching numbers with non-digits embedded*. So I think a proposed regex should not match a line with no digits at all. Yours matches `test`.

Comment: Yes but it seems to be a mixture.

Comment: This works. It takes some massaging to get it from the command line but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^\d\s])\S+$
```

This means "at least one digit and one non-digit and no whitespace".

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/Ci8Pp5nMxt).

---

If no newlines were in your input, you could use slightly simpler:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*\D)\S+$
```

Comment: Your first regex matches digit-only strings but second is OK.

Comment: @revo the first one works if there are no newlines - see [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/v75FK3nMnV)

Comment: Only if there is no new lines. You can avoid it `^(?=.*\d)(?=.*\D(?!^))\S+$`

Comment: @revo I just re-read Q, and input has newlines... Answer updated accordingly. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to dodge strings made up entirely of digits, or entirely of letters. So you can exclude those. That will also let in strings without *any* numbers, so also require a number.

```
my $exclude = qr/(?: [0-9]+ | [A-Za-z]+ )/x;
my @res = grep { not /^$exclude$/ and /\d/ } @strings;
```

If any other characters need be excluded (underscore?), add it to the list.

It is not clear how your input is coming, this takes a list of ready strings. Add word boundaries and/or `/s`, depending on the input. Or parse the input into a list of strings for this.

---

If input comes as as a multi-line string, `my @strings = split '\n|\s+', $text;`.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you over-thinking this massively? What's wrong with using `/\D/` to match a string that contains a non-digit?

I'm not sure what your exact requirements are, but if you're looking for a string that contains at least one digit and at least one non-digit, then the easiest approach is to use to regex matches - `/\d/ && /\D/`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  say "$_: " . (/\d/ && /\D/ ? 'matches' : 'doesn\'t match');
}

__DATA__
v2.1
-98.7
3.141
.6180
9,000
+42
555.123.4567
+1-(800)-555-2468
0123456789
12345
```